# Error rising in gitlab configuration file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

> 2024-03-29T10:24:52+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:  /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:2363: unknown regexp options - var ...porter['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/pgbouncer-exporte... ...                           ^~ /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:2363: sy

How to resolve this error? The line 2363, here is commented but I don't know why the error rises from that line. Please provide debugging suggestions to resolve this error